# What should I include in my first email to a potential PhD advisor?

Tags: phd, advisor, application, email

I am applying for Ph.D program, and I need to find an advisor to accept me in his group. I want to send to him a perfect email and get his attention to me.
I would like some opinion on this matter.

- Do I include my CV and recondition letter in the first email?
- Do I mention my GPA?
- Do I straight-up ask them if they are accepting students? Or, do I first attempt to establish a relationship?

The field is renewable energy.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. In the future, please [edit] your question to improve it instead of asking a new question. Also please be aware of [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90725/7734).

Comment: Also, what is a “recondition letter”? Do you mean a recommendation letter by any chance?

Comment: [This](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28270/7734) and [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/252/7734) seem to address most of what you are asking. If you have any remaining questions, please [edit] yours to focus on them and to clarify why the aforementioned questions do not help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not write a generic email to 50 faculty members. You need to focus on a few that you think are a good fit. For example, many faculty members won’t take you because they don’t have funding.

Next, try to make a personal connection: read their papers before, see how you could contribute, and tell them.

If you have a connection to them (you took a class/worked with a colleague of theirs, mentioning them will be a massive bonus (in terms of likelihood of receiving a reply).

Good luck!